# How to know that Room's onCreate() callback is over

Tags: java, android, android-room

I'm working on an app that uses `Room` database; it's a static database that has 3 tables that I insert their data at the first time the app launches by overriding `onCreate()` upon database instantiation.

It takes a while until inserting all the static records to the three tables, so my app can't access database until the `onCreate()` is over to get the right data back to be shown to the user.

When I try to access the database within the activity's `onCreate()` method, it returns `null` data, and this literally interrupts the Room's `onCreate` operation, which lead to null data for upcoming launches of the app as the Room's `onCreate()` is called only once.

For debugging purpose, when I get rid of this database access only for the first time launch of the app (after clean uninstall) to allow the database to build-up for the first launch; then when I re-add the database query to my  activity's `onCreate()` and relaunch the app; it returns non-null data; I just wanted to make sure that Room's `onCreate()` is over of the 1st launch.

I can pass a listener to the custom Room RoomDatabase class where its callback can be triggered upon the end of `onCreate()` method; but I'm not sure if this is the right way to do this or there is another elegant way, and if this is the right way; then how to implement it the right way taking the MVVM design pattern, stuff like `Repository`, `ViewModel` into consideration.

Here's how the database class looks like

```
@Database(entities = {Table1.class, Table2.class, Table3.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database.db";
    private static volatile AppDatabase INSTANCE;
    private static final Object LOCK = new Object();

    public abstract Table1Dao getTable1Dao();
    public abstract Table2Dao getTable2Dao();
    public abstract Table2Dao getTable3Dao();

    private static Executor mExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();


    static public AppDatabase getInstance(final Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            synchronized (LOCK) {
                if (INSTANCE == null) {
                    INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                            AppDatabase.class, DATABASE_NAME)
                            .addCallback(new Callback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
                                    mExecutor.execute(() -> table1InsertOperation(context));
                                    mExecutor.execute(() -> table2InsertOperation(context));
                                    mExecutor.execute(() -> table3InsertOperation(context));
                                   super.onCreate(db);
                                }
                            })
                            .build();
                }
            }
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

}
```

Do appreciate your help

Comment: Does "static database" mean that it is a fixed, read-only resource?

Comment: @Bob Snyder yeah that's right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a development version of your app or other tool (e.g. [sqlite3](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sqlite3)) to create a database file containing your fixed data.  Place the DB file in your app's `assets/` directory and use it to [prepopulate your database](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/prepopulate).

See the docs for [createFromAsset()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RoomDatabase.Builder#createFromAsset(java.lang.String)) for details.

The think the resulting app database will be ready for use immediately after returning from [RoomDatabase.build()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RoomDatabase.Builder).  You could also use the [onOpen()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RoomDatabase.Callback#onOpen(androidx.sqlite.db.SupportSQLiteDatabase)) callback.

Comment: Thanks so much Bob .. I will be trying to do that, hopefully it won't affect the app size

Answer (score 1):

"When I try to access the database within the activity's onCreate() method, it returns null data, and this literally interrupts the Room's onCreate operation, which lead to null data for upcoming launches of the app as the Room's onCreate() is called only once."
This seems pretty weird to me, a db is made to allow multiple threads to read and write, so why that should happen?

"I can pass a listener to the custom Room RoomDatabase class where its callback can be triggered upon the end of onCreate() method" I see you use an Executor to run the population phase on background threads, so onCreate should finish almost immediately, the threads that populate the db most probably much later. You would have to monitor when all the three threads you run all finish their work. 
Same as the listener, but much easier (once you solve point 1 that seems a bug somewhere in your code or less probably in Room) would be just to have a LiveData (or Flow) that tells you when all the rows are inserted.

Look at this repo: https://gist.github.com/florina-muntenescu/697e543652b03d3d2a06703f5d6b44b5
she uses an `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` and seems similar to what you do

Ps. Android Studio 4.1 has an amazing Database Inspector, try it!

Comment: Hi Andrew .. you're right, but the problem that I try to access the database with a query while it's still building the initial data with its CallBack ... this access interrupts the operation of this callback (which is inserting the intial data in the 3 tables) ... so when I relaunch the app again it finds null data on Room database as Room's OnCreate can only be called once and only once as documentation says. Thanks for your answer and for the shared repo

Comment: Hi @Zain, an access (read or write) to a database doesn't interrupt any other operation on the same database. You can spawn one million threads and do all the sort of operations (select, insert, update and deletes) in those. the database will stay always consistent. Yes, you could have for example an error if in one thread you insert a row with the same id of a row that was already inserted from another thread, and that error could stop all the subsequent operations of a transaction. but you need to post what you do on the populate functions and on the other access to see if that's the case.

Comment: you said "it's a static database that has 3 tables that I insert their data at the first time" so i thought you would do all the insert on your populate phase and only select on the access, which should not give problems. By the way, why you use 3 threads on the onCreate? could be that the randomisation of order of operations given by the 3 threads causes randomly the problem? I'd go with one thread there (the db most probably parallelise the operations with his thread pool anyway)

Comment: Can I put the three insertions into a single thread? let me try that

Comment: For for database access, I just have a single Query of the list of items of one of the tables in activity onCreate()

Comment: I got now different results .. for the first launch I got null data (seems like the callback is working) .. the second launch the data comes in and shown .. I guess I can solve this by using LiveData, but actually I just want to get the data only once as it's read-only

Comment: It's normal that you could get different data based on when the threads execute their operations, to make thinks easier for the developer, Room can return a LiveData, so you can observe on that LiveData and your UI will be updated when the data changes (in your case when the insert finishes, if the select was run before).

Comment: thanks again, is there a way to stop observing a LiveData at some point of the program?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216170/discussion-between-zain-and-andrewbloom).